# PHP: Date not updating in Column pulled from Database (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new at PHP and can't seem to find a way to display the correct time in a table.
The format of the time is correct, but it displays the date from the first row on all the following rows in the while-loop as well. I think for some reason the variable isn't overwritten.
What should I change so I can display the correct time?

Here's my code snippet.

```
<?php
// Variables
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "Clothes";
$dberror1 = "Could not connect to database.";
$dberror2 = "Could not select database.";
$dberror3 = "Could not execute query.";


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ($dberror1);

$select_db = mysql_select_db('Clothes') or die ($dberror2);


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>Colour</th>
<th>Fabric</th>
<th>Pattern</th>
<th>PurchaseDate</th>
</tr>";

$query = "SELECT b.Brand, c.Colour, f.Fabric, p.Pattern, d.Date 
FROM TSHIRTS AS t, Brands as b, Fabrics AS f, Patterns AS p,PurchaseDates as d, Colours as c 
WHERE b.ID=t.Brand 
AND c.ID=t.Colour 
AND p.ID=t.Pattern 
AND f.ID=t.Fabric 
AND d.ID=t.PurchaseDate
ORDER BY PATTERN;";


$fetch = mysql_query($query) or die($dberror3);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Brand']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Colour']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Fabric']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Pattern']."</td>";
    $date = new DateTime($row['PurchaseDate']);
    echo "<td>".$date->format('Y-m-d')."</td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's displaying the time from the 1st row?  I suspect it is just displaying todays date because $row['PurchaseDate'] doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use var_dump($row); to check what you're getting, then you will see whats wrong.  You are not selecting a field called PurchaseDate.  Also, I think Date is a reserved keyword, so you should quote it.

```
$query = "SELECT b.Brand, c.Colour, f.Fabric, p.Pattern, d.`Date` as PurchaseDate
FROM TSHIRTS AS t, Brands as b, Fabrics AS f, Patterns AS p,PurchaseDates as d, Colours as c 
WHERE b.ID=t.Brand 
AND c.ID=t.Colour 
AND p.ID=t.Pattern 
AND f.ID=t.Fabric 
AND d.ID=t.PurchaseDate
ORDER BY PATTERN;";


$fetch = mysql_query($query) or die($dberror3);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Brand']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Colour']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Fabric']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Pattern']."</td>";
    $date = new DateTime($row['PurchaseDate']);
    echo "<td>".$date->format('Y-m-d')."</td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You were right about the reversed keyword, quoting it fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// Variables
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "Clothes";
$dberror1 = "Could not connect to database.";
$dberror2 = "Could not select database.";
$dberror3 = "Could not execute query.";


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ($dberror1);

$select_db = mysql_select_db('Clothes') or die ($dberror2);


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>Colour</th>
<th>Fabric</th>
<th>Pattern</th>
<th>PurchaseDate</th>
</tr>";

$query = "SELECT b.Brand, c.Colour, f.Fabric, p.Pattern, d.Date 
FROM TSHIRTS AS t, Brands as b, Fabrics AS f, Patterns AS p,PurchaseDates, Colours as c 
WHERE b.ID=t.Brand 
AND c.ID=t.Colour 
AND p.ID=t.Pattern 
AND f.ID=t.Fabric 
AND d.ID=t.PurchaseDate
ORDER BY PATTERN;";


$fetch = mysql_query($query) or die($dberror3);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Brand']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Colour']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Fabric']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Pattern']."</td>";
    $date = new DateTime($row['PurchaseDates']);
    echo "<td>".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP')."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

This will work.